# Favicon going back to default when opening a new window

Tags: frontend

I have changed my store favicon and it works perfectly when navigating through my store. However when i open a datasheet from my products a new window opens up displaying the PDF file, however my favicon changes back to the magento default icon, does anybody know how to change this or why it happens.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens, because magento stores the favicon in skin:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"
    href="http://example.com/skin/frontend/enterprise/example/favicon.ico"  />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"
    href="http://example.com/skin/frontend/enterprise/example/favicon.ico"  />
```

When you open a PDF, there is no HTML behind, therefore no head and therefore no favicon definition, so your browser falls back on the default position of the favicon, which is `http://example.com/favicon.ico` and obviously you didn't change this icon.

If you have more than one domain, you should think about using a rewrite in `htconf` or `htaccess` instead of changing the file, because you can only have one `favicon.ico` in the root ;-)

Comment: Great explanation so thank you very much!! but i am very new to magento so where about would i have to go to change the http://example.com/favicon.ico icon ?? thank you

Comment: the file itself lives in the root directory, beside the `index.php`, `cron.php` and `api.php`. So you only have one favicon, just change this file against the one in your skin (copy it! not move ;-))

Comment: every time I copy over my favicon to the root directory it overrides it to the default magento one. Even if i delete the magento favicon out of the directory then upload my one. When iclick preview it still shows the default one. One ideas?

Comment: delete the cache of your browser.